# Is it possible to only share specific games through Steam Family Sharing?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

On my steam account, I have some games that I don't particularly want my sister to play, but I want to share my Terraria game with her so she can play with her friends.

Is it possible to only share Terraria with her through Family Sharing but no other games?

Comment: Who do you mean when you say “her” in the question? Are you trying to use Family Sharing feature or are you trying to use the Parental Controls feature?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie My mind moved faster than my hands. I edited the question to include those points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to exclude games from Steam Shared Library?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/297430/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-games-from-steam-shared-library)

Comment: @Dragonrage That question was marked as a duplicate of this one...

Comment: @Cyberson it should've been the other way around. The other question was better with more answers.

Comment: @Dragonrage I think the other one got marked as a duplicate because this question preceded it by about 8 months and they were addressing the same issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To an extent, yes and no.

As the [Steam Family Sharing FAQ](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing) says,

> *Can I share specific games, or do I have to share my whole library?*
>
> Libraries are shared and borrowed in their entirety.

That's the "no" part. However technically there is a way to enable only selected games for accounts you're sharing with. You can do this by using **Family Options.** Here's how.

**First,** login to the account you want to be used (the account you want the game[s] to be shared with) to unlock the library.

**Secondly,** then with that account logged in, activate the Family Options with a set PIN.

Then whenever you want to set a suitable game for that person, log yourself into their Steam client, unlock Family Mode with the PIN, and set the new game to " Family Games" and then lock the account again.

Comment: Are you sure that the Family Options method actually works? Have you used it yourself? I'm trying to set this up, but shared games are not available for selection in the Family View (even though they are visible with it turned off). I can only select games owned by the secondary account itself.

Comment: Nevermind, it *does* work - but you need to select those games by right-clicking them in the library and selecting "Add to Family Games". It just doesn't show up in the Family View settings (unlike the games that the account owns). But I'm going to keep these comments here, in case anyone else runs into the same issue.