# Is there a way to exclude games from Steam Shared Library?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

I know there is a list of games that are excluded when you share a library on steam, but I was wondering if there is also a way to exclude some additional games?

Comment: Whats preventing you from removing game from family sharing entirely?

Comment: Do you mean I should stop sharing my library or remove the game from my library?

Comment: Remove a single game from sharing by pressing right click on it in Library -> remove from family sharing

Comment: That would be exactly what I am looking for, but I'm afraid I don't see the option to remove it from family sharing.

Comment: ill check this from home to be sure im not giving you crap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you setup the account you're sharing with as a child account you will be able to select which games it can access from the parental settings.

Comment: Upvote, yep, that's what I was trying to make screenshot of, but failed to remember at home.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work in my particular case, but thank you for showing it can be done!

Comment: Are you sure this actually works - have you used it yourself? I'm trying to set this up, but shared games are not available for selection in the Family View (even though they are visible with it turned off). I can only select games that the secondary account actually owns.

Comment: Nevermind, it *does* work - but you need to select those games by right-clicking them in the library and selecting "Add to Family Games". It doesn't work via the Family View settings (unlike with games the account owns). I'm going to keep these comments here, in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker thanks for the update, saves me the trouble of double checking :-)

Comment: Official FAQ about the **Family View** feature: https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/6B1A-66BE-E911-3D98

Answer (score 6):

According to a FAQ put together on the Steam Family Sharing group on Steam, no there is no way to manually select games that you do not share with the account you are sharing with. Meaning the only games that are restricted from sharing are of course the ones that are restricted by default.

Source: [Family Sharing FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/0/648811126417092378/?)

Comment: Hm.. I don't know how i missed that. Thank you

Comment: "there is no way to manually select games that you do not share", that was just too strong statement to remain valid

Answer (score 4):

You need to activate Family Mode and then one by one remove games you dont want to show (or other way around if different default setting turned on).

Cause I wasnt launching Steam for half month or so, here is Internet for the win:
http://www.rosary.catholic.edu.au/__files/f/5062/Factsheet_Parents_Steam.pdf
page 3.

P.S, never was thinking I'll say thanks to Catholic educational school/web-site

Answer (score 0):

No, when sharing a library, the whole content is available for the person you are sharing it with.

[Source](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing)